# Cakephp: how to get full url to the current request/page

Tags: cakephp-3.3

Some body please help me how to get full url i.e with scheme and host of the current page in the view. I tried the following, but didnt return the expected results

```
$this->request->here; // returns uri plus base path. no host & scheme
$this->request->here(true); // same problem
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?= $this->Url->build(null, true); ?>
```

Here you are more info:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/url.html#generating-urls

Answer (score 2):

You can get domain,scheme,path like this :

```
use Cake\Routing\Router;
$domain = parse_url(Router::url('/', true));
pr($domain);
```

OR

```
use Cake\Routing\Router;
$url = Router::url(null, true);
```

Controller,action path can be get by :

```
$this->request->here
```

Comment: i want a string full based url not array

Comment: $domain['scheme'].'://'.$domain['host'].$this->request->here plz use this. you can get full url in string

Comment: jakcep's answer is straightforward.your answer can be improved  by directly  returning  Router::url(null, true); thnks

Comment: @CholthiPaulTtiopic Thanks Man :)